# What's wrong with my swap mounting?

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, mount, fstab, swap

On Ubuntu 16.04, the linux swap does not mount automatically. The `Mount Options` is disable.

[image: disk]

My fstab:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/isw_cbdddhahdj_Volume1p2 /               ext4    noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_cbdddhahdj_Volume1p1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5f207b84-3c08-45fd-ae8c-c2a05621a7f2 /mnt/5f207b84-3c08-45fd-ae8c-c2a05621a7f2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

After mounting manually,

```
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-1 partition 7.5G   0B   -1
```

Comment: Please can you add the output of `swapon --show` in the question

Comment: `swapon --show` shows nothing before mounting. After manual mounting, it shows sth.

Comment: Ive never used LVM, but is `/dev/mapper/isw_cbdddhahdj_Volume1p1`, the same as `/dev/dm-1`? I would have expected line in fstab along the lines of `/dev/dm-1 none swap sw 0 0`